# Constructing a continuous linear functional

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $C$ be the Banach space of complex continuous functions on $[0,1]$, with the supremum norm. Let $B$ be the closed unit ball of $C$. Show that there exist continuous linear functionals $\phi$ on $C$ for which $\phi(B)$ is an open subset of the complex plane; in particular $|\phi|$ attains no maximum on $B$.

I had tried it several times but I am not able to generate such a linear  continuous functional on the given space.
Any type of help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance